# Given a TemporalData object, can I determine whether it's a TimeSeries or an EventSeries?

Tags: time-series

If I have a function that accepts `TemporalData` objects, is there some mechanism whereby it can determine what kind of object it gets (`TimeSeries` vs. `EventSeries`)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
data = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 10];
ts = TimeSeries[data, Automatic];
es = EventSeries[data, Automatic];

First/@{es, ts}
```

> {EventSeries, TimeSeries}

or

```
eventSeriesQ = First@#===EventSeries &

eventSeriesQ/@{es, ts}
```

> {True, False}